# Base type page is specified in other parts

Tags: uwp, resharper

Even though XAML pages inherit automatically from Page, ReSharper grays out all inheritance from that Base class and comes up with the following message:

```
Base type page is specified in other parts
```

It suggests removing redundant super type references.

[image]

What is the interpretation of all this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code-behind `MainPage` class is a `partial` class. The other part is defined in XAML like this -

```
<Page x:Class="xxx.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      ...
</Page>
```

This markup is already saying the `MainPage` inherits from `Page`, so doing it again in the code-behind is redundant and that's why Resharper is marking it.